# Scala regex find matches in middle of string

Tags: regex, scala

I have written the following code in scala:

```
val regex_str = "([a-z]+)(\\d+)".r
"_abc123" match {
  case regex_str(a, n) => "found"
  case _ => "other"
}
```

which returns "other", but if I take off the leading underscore:

```
val regex_str = "([a-z]+)(\\d+)".r
"abc123" match {
  case regex_str(a, n) => "found"
  case _ => "other"
}
```

I get `"found"`. How can I find any `([a-z]+)(\\d+)` instead of just at the beginning? I am used to other regex languages where you use a `^` to specify beginning of the string, and the absence of that just gets all matches.

Answer (score 5):

Scala regex patterns default as "anchored", i.e. bound to beginning and end of target string.

You'll get the expected match with this.

```
val regex_str = "([a-z]+)(\\d+)".r.unanchored
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi May be you need something like this,

```
val regex_str = "[^>]([a-z]+)(\\d+)".r
"_abc123" match {
  case regex_str(a, n) => println(s"found $a $n")
  case _ => println("other")
}
```

This will avoid the first character from your string.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The `unapplySeq` of the `Regex` tries to capture the whole input by default (treats the pattern as if it was between `^` and `$`).
There are two ways to capture inside the input:

- use `.*` before and after the captures: `val regex_str = ".*([a-z]+)(\\d+).*".r`
- do the same with `.unanchored`: `val regex_str = "([a-z]+)(\\d+)".r.unanchored`

Otherwise scala treats regular expression anchors the same way as in other languages; this one is an exception made for semantic reasons.

Comment: The greedy ".*" will eat everything, and "([a-z]+)" will match only the last "c". You probably wanted ".*?" instead of ".*" in the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

The regex extractor in scala pattern-matching attempts to match the entire string. If you want to skip some junk-characters in the beginning and in the end, prepend a `.` with a *reluctant quantifier* to the regex:

```
val regex_str = ".*?([a-z]+)(\\d+).*".r
val result = "_!+<>__abc123_%$" match {
  case regex_str(a, n) => s"found a = '$a', n = '$n'"
  case _ => "no match"
}

println(result)
```

This outputs:

```
found a = 'abc', n = '123'
```

Otherwise, don't use the pattern match with the extractor, use `"...".r.findAllIn` to find all matches.